# What's the different between Python ABI "cp37" and "cp37m"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been playing around with `pip3 download` and found that some packages were obtainable by specifying a Python ABI of `cp37m`, while others were obtainable by specifying a Python ABI of `cp37`.

What's the different between the `cp37m` and `cp37` ABIs, and where can I find a list of available ABIs with  descriptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `m` means it's for Python 3.7 with the pymalloc extension. From [PEP 314](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/#proposal)

- `d` with pydebug extension
- `m` with pymalloc extension
- `u` withe wide unicode extension

Comment: Thank you. How can I see which extensions my Python is compiled with? I.e which ABIs it supports. Also, do you know of any list of Python ABIs, or is it always “cp37” (for C-Python 3.7) and none or one of the three characters above, `d`, `m`, `u` appended? Will `cp37` automatically download packages with `d`, `m`, `u`, if no package is available for "cp37" and the Python implementation supports those extensions?

Comment: [sys.abiflags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=abi#sys.abiflags). I'm not sure how pip handles what to download if a specific abi package isn't available.

Comment: On my system, `sys.abiflags` is `''`?

Comment: Then your Python doesn't have any extensions enabled.

Comment: Ohh, I see. It's Python 3.8.2 download using `brew`. Thanks.